# In BigQuery, is there anything similar to @@ROWCOUNT that can be used in a BigQuery stored procedure?

Tags: google-bigquery, rowcount

In SQL Server, if you want to get the number of rows affected by the last statement, you can use `@@ROWCOUNT`. In Teradata, we have `ACTIVITY_COUNT`.

What's the equivalent in BigQuery?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[@@row_count](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/scripting#system-variables) was released only recently, try:

```sql
create temp table t as select 1 x;
delete from t where true;

select @@row_count;
```

Comment: eager to see all the great new stuff from you guys!! any ideas when we will see it?

Comment: Amazing.. Thanks very much @YunZhang.. May I know what is your source of information (BigQuery)? I have been looking for it but couldnt find any.

Comment: @Bryan I implemented it.

Comment: Wow, Thanks @YunZhang . Do you know if something similar to EXECUTE IMMEDIATE will be rolled out in BigQuery?

Comment: It is also planned.

Comment: @Bryan documentation also published: https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/scripting#system-variables

Comment: Here's yet another URL for those 'system variables': 
 https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/system-variables